# Binding style property outside itemsource?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've a combobox like this:

```
   <ComboBox x:Name="CountryMenuComboBox" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}">

        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsRemoving}" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

what I need to do is enable or disable the items inside the combobox using the property `IsRemoving`, but this property isn't located inside the itemsource `Countries`, so I need to access outside the itemsource. How can I do this for a style?

Comment: If you can’t tell us where the property *is* located, the question can’t be answered. Is it on the parent viewmodel that owns the `Countries` property? If so, try `IsEnabled=“{Binding DataContext.IsRemoving, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}”`

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes sorry, the countries property is located in the same viewmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `IsRemoving` a property of the parent viewmodel that owns the `Countries` property? If so, try `<Setter Property=“IsEnabled” Value=“{Binding DataContext.IsRemoving, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ComboBox}}” />`

Comment: I don't understand a thing: IsEnabled should be place on the setter? or where?

Comment: Same place it is now. Just add the RelativeSource part.

Comment: so something like: `<Setter Property="IsEnabled={Binding }"` ..?

Comment: Just like you had it but change the binding like I said.

Comment: oh so you mean IsRemoving not IsEnabled, typo error?

Comment: Sorry, see update. I’ve doing three things at once here, my bad.

Comment: ok got it, but I get this error: `'IsRemoving' property not found on 'object' ''ComboBox'`

Comment: Right, it’s on the DataContext of the ComboBox. That’s why the binding Path in my answer is `DataContext.IsRemoving`

Comment: so if the property is on another datacontext I just need to specify the datacontext name.IsRemoving?

Comment: You need to copy my setter and paste it into your XAML. There’s no such thing as a “DataContext name”